# Error in implementing SVC in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to implement svc for predicting a continuous variable:

```
print("X_train_dtm type ", type(X_train_dtm))
print("y_train type ", type(y_train))
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
```

However I am getting the following output and error:

```
X_train_dtm type  <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
y_train type  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)

ValueError: Unknown label type: 72      0.526
350     0.253
457     0.763
2       0.340
1044   -0.223
241    -0.364
979     0.357
892    -0.384
969    -0.114
761    -0.285
866     0.516
559     0.295
73      0.328
117    -0.130
```

I tried quite a few things but not able to fix it.

Comment: You cannot use float values in the label. Convert to int or str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVC stands for C-Support Vector Classification.
The algorithm is a classification algorithm and cannot predict continues data. Instead you should use regression algorithms. You can check [SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) algorithm which also uses support vector machines or other regression algorithms (Linear Regression, Lasso, Random Forest Regression and many others).

Good luck!